# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 while installing requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pip

I have been trying to install packages from a requirements.txt file but I'm getting error. I made a virtual environment to install the packages but got his huge array. My machine is running on python 3.8

Below is the error what I got in my terminal while trying to install the requirements.txt file in my virutal environment

```
 Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzo50rwzk'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dpmca2i7\scipy
    Complete output (170 lines):
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\demoProjectwebapp-v3\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\demoProjectwebapp-v3\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\demoProjectwebapp-v3\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\demoProjectwebapp-v3\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    setup.py:111: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp
    setup.py:386: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-fv_m7gz4'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
    Running from scipy source directory.
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 505, in <module>
      File "setup.py", line 501, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-glp1ljn7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
        raise NotFoundError(msg)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\Documents\demoProjectwebapp-v3\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzo50rwzk' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You installation depends on a compiler, which is missing from a system. Were there any docs supplied with the package?

Comment: nah there weren't any  docs. it just said to install the dependencies from the requriements.txt file

Comment: Could we see the actual modules inside of requirements.txt?

Comment: sure. https://paste.pythondiscord.com/dowobohayo.ini @lustin

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem installing torch?

Comment: but I would need that for the python file to run. should I remove torch from requirements and install it manually later? or is there another solution @Evgeny

Answer (score 0):

Try isolate which line of requirements.txt gives you an error, you can try comment out torch and see how installation goes without it.

To replicate your error message try pip install torch, I think it would give you the error message you experienced.

Two things after that:

- go to torch documentation, find out about manual installation
- try installing with conda, another package manager

Also, you may want to install Anaconda package bundle to try if most libraries are there.

As a side note - bad experience in installing some heavy dependency happens often, so treat it as excercise, it is not something you did wrong, it is kind of nature of dependencies you try using. Good luck!